# chart.jsのtick表示を間引きたい

Tags: javascript, chart.js

お世話になっております。

webページ上に線グラフを表示するためにchart.jsを使っています。
その際、Y軸のtick表示を間引きたいのですが、グリッド線は残しておきたいのです。

出来ればchart.jsそのものは弄る事無く実現したいのですが、
何か方法があればアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

-----補足-----
使用しているchart.jsのバージョンを記載しておりませんでした。
chart.js　2.7.2　になります。
ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ticks の callback を使うと[ラベルの書式を変更することができる](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats)ので、これを使うとたとえば奇数番目のラベルだけ消すといったことができます。

```js
callback: function(value, index, values) {
    if (index % 2 === 1) {
        return "";
    }
    return value;
}
```

以下は Chart.js 2.7.2 を使った実装例です。

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("sampleChart").getContext("2d");
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "sample",
            data: [
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random()
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0.0,
                    suggestedMax: 1.0,
                    stepSize: 0.1,
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        if (index % 2 === 1) {
                            return "";
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
var sampleChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
div#chart {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"><canvas id="sampleChart"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: 具体的なソースコードを載せてくださいまして、ありがとうございます。
"ticks"のcallback関数を弄ってはいたのですが、グリッド線まで消えてしまっていました。
return "";
で空の文字列を返すことで、グリッド線を残しつつラベルを消すことができるのですね。
大変勉強になりました。
ありがとうございました。