# chart.js レーダーチャートの目盛表示間隔を調整したい

Tags: chart.js

具体的には、一番最初の刻みをやや小さくしたいです。何かいい方法ありますか？

chart.jsバージョン 2.9.3

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        stepSize: 1,        ← 一番目の間隔を0.5ほどにしたい。他は１のままで
        display: false, 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridLines` の 幅指定 `lineWidth` を  0 にすることで線を引かなくすることができます。
0.5 間隔に設定して 線を引きたくない場所は 線の幅を 0 にします。

```
options: {
    scale: {
        gridLines: {
            lineWidth: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
        },
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            stepSize: 0.5, // ← 一番目の間隔を0.5ほどにしたい。他は１のままで
            display: false                              
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 描画したグラフ]

参考までに
[chart.jsのtick表示を間引きたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43200/chart-js%E3%81%AEtick%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%82%92%E9%96%93%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
を参考にして ラベル表示の ON OFF を制御すると 下記のような図も作成できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございました。
できました！！！
範囲を0～4.5にして、0.5間隔で設定したらきれいに表示できました。

Comment: あ、線を引きたいのは 0.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 , 4.5 の場所だったんですね。 最初だけ 0.5 って不思議だな・・と思ってたんです。